# What determines the GUI file chooser launched by applications?

Tags: configuration, kde, gui, file-manager

I am using KDE (Kubuntu), and I noticed that different GUI programs when launching a file chooser seem to use 3-4 different types of file choosers. Some are more annoying in that they do not seem to allow me to type the file path.

Where are these different file chooser dialogues coming from? Can I either override which file chooser is used or find out the name of the file chooser so I can see if there are any keyboard shortcuts available?

Example of one that does not allow me to type a path, this time from `git-cola`:
[image: git-cola and some other programs]

And the standard one, this time from `chromium-browser`:
[image: "KDialog"]

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/607476/what-controls-the-native-default-file-chooser-that-applications-use-in-linux